# How to get RealmSwift working with Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I've been trying to get started with Realm (version 4.3.0) as a database option with Xcode 11. With my Googling skills I could not get an answer for my problems. I've tried to use the [Official Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) but it appears that the way they do things is not working with Xcode 11. Basic code:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    class Test: Object {
        @objc dynamic var text = ""
        @objc dynamic var internalId = 0
    }

    let newTest = Test()
    newTest.text = "Text" // Errors happen here



    print("text: \(newTest.text)")

}
```

I get an errors that I definitely was not expecting:

- Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
- Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration
- Expected '{' in body of function declaration
- Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration
- Expected declaration
- Invalid redeclaration of 'newTest()'

Also when I'm trying to initialize and write to Realm with:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write { // Error here
   realm.add(newTest)
}
```

I get the error of "Expected declaration"

From what I've read, Realm seems like a really nice database option for iOS, but with these problems, I cannot get up and running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're creating a instance of at class level. Place all three lines (creation, modification and the print) inside viewDidLoad() method. Besides that, move your Test class outisde ViewController's, preferably on its own file.

Comment: @108g That worked! Thanks a ton! Still having a hard time figuring out where everything needs to be in Swift.

Comment: No problem, take a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rearrange the code so the objects and functions are in their correct place.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

//this makes the class available throughout the app
class Test: Object {
   @objc dynamic var text = ""
   @objc dynamic var internalId = 0
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


       //create a new realm object in memory
       let newTest = Test()
       newTest.text = "Text"

       print("text: \(newTest.text)")

       //persist the object to realm
       let realm = try! Realm()
       try! realm.write {
          realm.add(newTest)
       }

       //or read objects
       let results = realm.objects(Test.self)
       for object in results {
          print(object.text)
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @108g commented: 
I was trying to create an instance at class level. So I moved the creation, modification and the print inside viewDidLoad() method. Then I moved my Test class into a new file.

So the code that works:
ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let newTest = Prompt()
        newTest.text = "Text"

        print("text: \(newTest.text)")


        let realm = try! Realm()

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newTest)
        }
    }
}
```

And RealmTest.swift (new file)

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Prompt: Object {
    @objc dynamic var text = ""
    @objc dynamic var internalId = 0
}
```